# Сброс значений калькулятора при клике javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var ah = {
  40: 8,
  45: 10,
  50: 11,
  55: 12,
  60: 14,
  65: 15,
  70: 16,
  75: 16,
  85: 17,
  90: 18,
  95: 19,
  100: 20,
  110: 21,
  120: 25,
  132: 30,
  140: 32,
  190: 42,
  200: 44,
  210: 46,
  220: 48,
  230: 50,

}

$(document).ready(function() {

function calcTotal() {
    $('#res1').html('');
    var op = $("#select-ah").val();
    var op1 = +ah[op];
    var v = +$("#val1").val();
    var total = op1 * v;
    var total2 = op1 * 0 * v;
var sbros = $(#reset1).click(function(){
    return total2;
};
//console.log(op, op1, v, total);
if (!isNaN(total)) {
  $('#res1').append($("<span></span>").text(total))
}
else if (sbros) {
  $('#res1').append($("<span></span>").text(sbros))
}
else {
  $('#res1').html('<span>Результат</span>');
};

  $('#minus').click(function() {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    var count = +$input.val();
    if (isNaN(count))
      count = 0;
    count--;
    count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
    $input.val(count);
    $input.change();
  });
  $('#plus').click(function() {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    var count = +$input.val();
    if (isNaN(count))
      count = 0;
    count++;
    $input.val(count);
    $input.change();
  });
  
  Object.keys(ah).forEach((item) => {
    $('#select-ah').append('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>');
  });
  
  $('#select-ah').change(calcTotal);
  $(".block__val input").change(calcTotal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-ah">
  <option>Выберите емкость (A/ч)</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="block__val" style="display:flex;justify-content: center;width:35%;">
  <span class="btn-btn1" id="minus">-</span>
  <input type="text" value="1" style="text-align: center;border-radius: 0px;" id="val1">
  <span class="btn-btn1" id="plus">+</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="price-itog">
  <p style="margin-top: 47px; color:#2E0648;">Стоимость: <span id="res1"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Длинный комментарий был бы, решил в виде ответа записать.

• `$(document)` документ в таком виде пишется без кавычек. А все селекторы классов и id обязательно должны быть с кавычками `$('#reset1')`

• Запись такого вида:

```
$('#reset1').click();
```

(а кстати, click() разве не убрали из последних версий jQ?) привязывает событие к элементу, который уже оказался на странице после загрузки. Он не будет работать, если элемент `id="reset1"` создается динамически. Поэтому там-сям так часто рекомендуют привыкать к записи такого вида:

```
$(document).on('click', '#reset1', function(){ ... });
```

В таком случае клик привязывается к документу. И при клике идет проверка, если у кликнутого элемента оказывается id="reset1", запускается функция.

• `append()` в целом достаточно "тяжелая" штука... к редактированию HTML страницы стоит прибегать только при реальной необходимости. А `.html()` или `innerHTML` - "тяжелее" (сперва смотрят на всё написанное, делают хитрую магию, а если там оказываются HTML элементы, через append добавляют элементы куда надо)

В вашем случае оптимальнее будет изначально держать на странице весь HTML, только всему, что должно быть изначально скрыто, добавить класс такого вида:

```
<style> .INVIS {display: none;} </style>
<div class="INVIS" id="reset1"> Меня не видно </div>
```

При необходимости, через jQuery уже можно переключать эту видимость:

Показать — `$('#reset1').show();` или скрыть: `$('#reset1').hide();`

• Проверку isNaN можно вовсе исключить, если вашим инпутам добавить `type="number"`
Тогда туда в принципе нельзя будет ничего ввести кроме чисел.

А не забывайте перед математическими операциями убедиться, что полученное число является именно числом (Number), а не строкой (String). Такая запись превращает строку в число:

```
var x = Number( $('#например').val() );
```

---

Не удержался, записал с нуля))

```js
//Чтобы лишний раз не проверять на NaN, поместил строку "выберите"
// сразу в объект, со значением 0 (будет 0, а не NaN)

var ah = {
  'Выберите емкость (А/ч)': 0,
  40: 8,
  45: 10,
  50: 11,
  55: 12,
  60: 14,
  65: 15,
  70: 16,
  75: 16,
  85: 17,
  90: 18,
  95: 19,
  100: 20,
  110: 21,
  120: 25,
  132: 30,
  140: 32,
  190: 42,
  200: 44,
  210: 46,
  220: 48,
  230: 50
}

//Здесь вы лишний раз записывали ничегонеделающий value="item". 

Object.keys(ah).forEach((item) => {
    $('#select-ah').append('<option>' + item + '</option>');
  });
$('#select-ah').val('Выберите емкость (А/ч)');

//Один раз записываем универсальную функцию-считалку и всё, вызываем её куда надо.
function count(){
  var index = $('#select-ah').val();
  var op = +ah[index];
  $('#res1').text( op*($('#val1').val()) );
}
//при вводе в инпут...
$(document).on('input','#val1',function(){ count(); });  
//при смене значения селекта...
$(document).on('change','#select-ah',function(){ count(); });
//при клике на +1 (сперва меняем значение, потом вызываем считалку)
$(document).on('click','#plus',function(){
  $('#val1').val( Number($('#val1').val()) + 1 ); count();
});
//при клике на -1
$(document).on('click','#minus',function(){
  var num = $('#val1').val() == 1 ? 0 : 1;
  $('#val1').val( Number($('#val1').val()) - num ); count();
});
//здесь ? называется "тернарный оператор" и является "коротким" if
//Общий вид: «Условие ? Значение при выполнении : Значение в других случаях»
//Проверяем, если значение инпута и так равно 1, от него делаем минус 0
//Иначе, минус 1

//Самый банальный сброс
$(document).on('click','#reset',function(){
  $('#val1').val(1);
  $('#res1').text(""); //Пустая строка
  $('#select-ah').val('Выберите емкость (А/ч)');
});
```

```css
input{width: 80px; text-align:center;font-size:30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Это плохой HTML. На скорую руку просто всегда оставляю только основные элементы. 
А когда скрипт готов, потом уже можно заняться внешним видом -->

<select id="select-ah"></select>

<br><br>
<button id="minus">-</button>
<input type="number" value="1" id="val1">
<button id="plus">+</button>

<br><br>
Стоимость: <span id="res1"></span>

<br><br>
<button id="reset">reset</button>
```

Если страница очень большая, с километровым JS, надо избегать глобальных переменных, чтобы например в случае совпадения названий переменных, одно не переписывало значение другого. Этому немного помогают const и let вместо var... но чтобы совсем надежно, можно прям весь написанный код пихнуть в `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Но в данном случае jQ длиннее чем JS) 

На чистом JS функцию надо будет поставить в левую сиську (  )(  );

```
(function(){ сюда весь код... это эквивалент $ready })();
```

Comment: Спасибо за содержательный ответ. Кавычки пропустил и правда, а в остальном не совсем понятно зачем добавлять класс, в моем случае мне надо обнулить значения калькулятора. То есть в поле res1 вывести 0, я подумал что правильнее всего будет создать переменную которая будет все полученные значения при клике умножать на 0

Comment: $('#res1').append($("<span></span>").text(total2)); что то типо такого, переменная total2 будет равна нулю. И это все нужно сделать при клике по кнопке "Сброс" (#reset1)

Comment: А можно никого никуда не умножать... а попросту обнулить: `$('#reset').on('click',function(){ $('#res1').text(0); });` и всё остальное, что нужно обнулить также... при клике взять и приравнять к нулю, без пересчета значения (которое и так должно после рассчетов домножаться на ноль) = так сразу можно сказать ему, что он равен нулю и всё) Если где-то выше был объявлен var total = .... который еще должен быть использован, то при клике на сброс, также можно просто записать `total = 0` (уже без var)

Comment: См ответ (отредактирован). Всё на деле легче, чем вы пытались сделать) Там пара строк всего... взять, да умножть два числа.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли! Особенно спасибо за поясняющие комментарии )